# What happens when y_true is all 0 in dice loss?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

[image]

A deep learning model is being trained using the above loss function, Dice coefficient. 
In training, "1 - $L_{dice}$" is applied as a loss function.

The model takes several images as input including samples which have all 0 target values and samples which have some target values(e.g. 1).

The question is, **Will the loss function work well even when true values are all 0?**

Comment: If your target column, the output you are training to produce, is all constant and all equals the same value, then there is really no information there. The ideal fit is if input then whatever the value was becomes output. You can’t train anything more sophisticated than that.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thanks. Then should i remove the images which have no any target pixels in training?

Comment: Stratified sampling, as long as you have information in the target variable column, should do a decent job. Are you saying that one instance of the target output is zero, or that all instances of the target output are zero?

Comment: @EngrStudent At first sample ratio(samples having any target pixels : samples having none of target pixels) is 5:5. And the latter is what i want.

Comment: I wish you could make “toy data” that captures the essence the nature of the problem in your question, so I could make an answer that spoke to it.